# Creating an object within an object

Tags: javascript, object

I want create an object within an object.
The object is called "After".
The code below doesn't recognize After as a sub object of strat.

After contains some information after a Gekko trade was made. Gekko is a trading platform written in JavaScript under nodeJS, where strategies consist  of JavaScript code.

```
var strat;
strat = {
    Gotcoins: false,        // To decide when to buy.
    BoughtAt: 0,            // candle.close (price of the crypto coin) 
    MaxPeek:-1,

    After :{   strategie: " ", lasttreeup: false, seenhammer: false, proceed: true},

    ShortDate: function (date) {
       var monthNames = [
        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
        "Apr", "May", "Jun", .....
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if its the best way but i found away around it, by placing asign an object later to it in the init routine of the strategy, this works.

```
var strat   // the strategy object.
strat = {
   After : '',
   init: function () {

    var initthisafter = {   strategie: '?', lasttreeup: false, seenhammer: false, proceed: true};
    this.After = initthisafter;  //object inside an object !
```